# How can I remove the first three characters of a column if they contain the word "to "?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table where the column [English] sometimes has data that contains the word "to ".

How can I remove the "to " from the fields in just those rows that have it. So that for example:

```
 to eat
```

would become

```
 eat
```

Comment: Are you wanting to only do that to values that start with `to ` or to everything that has `to` in it?  Your question and title conflict.

Comment: I would like to only do rows where the column starts with "to ".  Sorry I was not very clear with the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use stuff:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ColumnName LIKE 'to %' THEN 
           STUFF(ColumnName, 1, 3, '')
       ELSE
           ColumnName 
       END As ColumnName 
FROM TableName
```

Another option is to use right with len:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ColumnName LIKE 'to %' THEN 
           RIGHT(ColumnName, LEN(ColumnName) - 3)
       ELSE
           ColumnName 
       END As ColumnName 
FROM TableName
```

Comment: I am sorry that I did not mention this but I only want to change "to " if it appears at the start of the text in the column.

Comment: And that is what my answer does.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
UPDATE TableName 
SET ColumnName = SUBSTRING(ColumnName,4,len(ColumnName))
WHERE ColumnName LIKE 'to %';
```

[Before and After image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npfuv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when CHARINDEX('to',column,0) = 0 then column
       else replace(column,'to ', '') end as column  --there is one space after 'to '

FROM TABLE
WHERE  --specify which rows here
```

Comment: if the value of the column is `to me and to you`, this would return `me and you`...

Comment: @ZoharPeled, right, I do not know what is the exact case, the example is bit of vague..

Comment: I am sorry that I did not mention this but I only want to change "to " if it appears at the start of the text in the column. The case will always be a lowercase t